# How to use AVG with Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have problem, i need make average of people who living in city.  In database i can found the number of living peaple like this

```
  SELECT CityName, (SELECT COUNT(*) from People where City.miestoID = 
    People.miestoID) as LivingPeople from City
```

and get this 
http://prntscr.com/p5dbin

Now i need make Average of the Living peaple in city. I try

```
  SELECT CityName, (SELECT AVG(COUNT(*) from People where City.miestoID = 
    People.miestoID)) as LivingPeople from City
```

Im using SSMS. I can't find any solution, but i know I am doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
select avg(LivingPeople)
from (
  select count(p.miestoID) as LivingPeople
  from City c
  left join People p on p.miestoID = c.miestoID
) x
```

Comment: c.CityName  is pretty much redundant here??

Comment: yep, removed it.

Comment: better to remove it yourself then trusting a query optimizer to remove it, not sure if a optimizer would detect that that CityName was never used on the outer SQL..

Answer (score 0):

if  you want to average from your query then you have to try like below

```
select avg(LivingPeople) from 
(SELECT CityName ,(SELECT COUNT(*) from People where City.miestoID = 
People.miestoID) as LivingPeople from City
) a
```

Comment: CityName  is pretty much redundant here?? Which also makes the subquery need redundant here..

Comment: subquery is also redundant.... Not sure if SQL Server optimizer would factor that out..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all cities have at least one person, you can do:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct miestoID);
from people;
```

The `* 1.0` is because SQL Server does integer division.

This divides the number of people by the number of cities.